# Inserting data but getting "duplicate values" error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, insert, duplicate-data

I am attempting inserting into an Access database, and the insert is successful (when I open the database the data is there), but I'm getting an error: "The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship.  Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again."

This is really confusing me.  No matter what I insert, it still gives me the same error.  And I don't understand why it's giving me an error even though it's working.  Here's my codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles Wizard1.FinishButtonClick
    'Collect Data
    Dim myDept = txtDept.Text
    Dim myFirst = txtFirstName.Text
    Dim myLast = txtLastName.Text
    Dim myPrefix = txtCoursePrefix.Text
    Dim myNum = txtCourseNum.Text

    'Define Connection
    Dim myConn As New OleDbConnection
    myConn.ConnectionString = AccessDataSource1.ConnectionString

    'Create commands
    Dim myIns1 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tableCourse (department, name_first, name_last, prefix, course_number) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", myConn)

    myIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myDept", myDept)
    myIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myFirst", myFirst)
    myIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myLast", myLast)
    myIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myPrefix", myPrefix)
    myIns1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myNum", myNum)

    'Execute the commands
    myConn.Open()
    myIns1.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to `.open` the connection before you build the command? Just a guess :)

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884185/en-us You should set the autonumber field to current maximum+1.  `ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN AutoNumFieldName COUNTER(iMaxID,1);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Access, so i first only posted it as comment. But [this kb-article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884185/en-us) sounds reasonable. You should set the autonumber field to current maximum+1.

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN AutoNumFieldName COUNTER(iMaxID,1);
```

It's worth a try. I don't know why its working anyway.

Comment: Well the thing is, I don't have an auto number, the prefix and course_number are my primary key fields.  But it's not like the data I'm entering duplicates any of those that are already in there, I'm entering something different every time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without testing on your DB, but this line

```
Dim myIns1 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tableCourse (department, name_first, name_last, prefix, course_number) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", myConn)
```

Seems like it would be better as:

```
Dim myIns1 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tableCourse (department, name_first, name_last, prefix, course_number) VALUES (?, '?', '?', '?', ?)", myConn)
```

In other words, the strings should be single-quoted and the numbers sent without quotes.

Beyond that, it looks like this particular Insert should work, but there may be a relationship between tableCourse and another table, and the referential integrity may be generating the error from the related table.

In other words, take a look at your 'Relationships'.

Comment: I doubt the quote thing would cause that kind of error, but I can try it.  I don't have any relationships in my database yet since I'm just testing it for now...

Answer (score 0):

Reseeding the table per MS directions didn't work for me. Required changing old unique index to a number field, and adding an entirely new unique index. Fortunately that index didn't link to other tables, which would have been a massive cluster if so, since you can't import values into a field and then convert that field to an autonumber for easy automatic index creation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The reason was that the type of ID in the Access table that I was trying to insert values was "Number" and not "AutoNumber". I changed it to "AutoNumber" and the problem was solved.